# exclude filter in google analytics match pattern

Tags: google-analytics

I want to exclude all referrals from a specific domain with subdomains

eg.

```
domain.com
subdomain.domain.com
www.domain.com
```

Have done this, but I can still see referrals from the specified domain

[image]

Comment: Try using Campaign Source instead of referral.

Comment: Your filter is incomplete in terms of the regex as it will only filter by exactly "dynaccount.com". You need to expand it with a wildcard to include sub domains: .*\.dynaccount\.com or if you already know the sub domains, the you could do: (www|subdomain)\.dynaccount\.com

Comment: It works after using `Campaign Source` :)